# Swap strings using strcpy

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to swap two strings by using only pointer notation, (no arrays), with
a function that looks like this

```
void str_switch(char *a, char *b)
```

the swapping should work irrespective of the sizes of b and a, and it is not known.

my idea is this:

```
void str_switch(char *a, char *b) {
const char *temp = a;
strcpy(b, temp);
}
```

however, after this, I am not sure how to copy b to a, because b changes, I tried declaring other constant pointers, but once I change b, I can never get the old version.

Comment: Can you not just swap the pointers around through a temp char*?  You'll need to pass char**.

Comment: I've tried to make the question clearer by referring to "swapping" rather than "switching", but I didn't want to change the code.

Comment: @martin yes I can do that but the function has to look like swap(char *b, char *a) not with type  char***

Comment: why did this post take downvotes it is really interesting as it tackles many problems ?!

Comment: @Meninx thanks, I don't know I guess the ones who know C well don't have a lot of patience, I started learning about pointers yesterday, so I agree it does tackle problems:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your strings are stored in allocated memories using functions like `malloc()`; thus this code works perfectly for that case,  especially as it **treats strings with different size and length**

```
    #include <stdio.h> // list of libraries that need to be included
    #include <stdlib.h> 
    #include <string.h> 

    void str_switch(char **a, char **b) {
    if (strlen(*a)>strlen(*b)) // check the strings with lowest size to reallocate
    {                          // in order to fit the big one
        char *temp=malloc((strlen(*a)+1)*sizeof(char)); // temp variable to preserve the lowest 
                                                    // the variable with lowest length                           
        strcpy(temp,*a); // store the longest string in its new location
        strcpy(*a,*b);
        free(*b); // free the allocated memory as we no longer need it
        *b=temp; // assign the new address location for the lowest string 
    }
    else if (strlen(*b)>strlen(*a)) // the same as above but invert a to b and b to a
    {
        char *temp=malloc((strlen(*b)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(temp,*b);
        strcpy(*b,*a);
        free(*a);
        *a=temp;
    }
    else // if the lengths are equal ==> @Morpfh solution
    {
        char *tmp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = tmp;
    }
 }
```

This is a test for function above (main code)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *a=malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    strcpy(a,"hello");
    char *b=malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
    strcpy(b,"bye");
    printf("a=%s\nb=%s\n",a,b);
    str_switch(&a,&b);
    printf("----------------------\n");
    printf("a=%s\nb=%s\n",a,b);


    return 0;
}
```

and we get

```
a=hello
b=bye
----------------------
a=bye
b=hello
```

Comment: An edit has been made to the code ! I just deleted the first `strcpy()` in the previous code as it is useless for the two first `if ()` condition ! you are welcome ! :)

Answer (score 2):

This strays from your question, heading in particular as `strcpy` is not used, and follow your comment to Martin James:

```
void str_switch(char **a, char **b) {
    char *tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

If you really want to use `strcpy` you'll have to know size of C-strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to allocate extra storage, you would need to switch the strings by swapping one character at a time.

If you are OK allocating extra storage, `strdup` a, `strcpy` b into a, `strcpy` the copy of a into b, then `free` the copy.

Comment: but even if I swap a character at a time, the smaller one will not have enough room for the bigger one, so if one of the strings looks like this a[] = "some string", and the other b[] = "ha", b wont have enough room for a?

Comment: You need to account for the fact that a larger buffer cannot fit into a smaller one. You will either need to allocate a bigger buffer, or stop when you run out of room. In either case, you will need to know the size of the buffers as you attempt to copy, so your function will have to update to include it. Or use `strlen` to dynamically determine it.

Comment: @Mcs If `a` abd `b` do not have enough room for each other, the function is pointless.

Comment: You do realize that you need to use `b` inside the function `str_switch` because the result won't be returned to the calling code?

Comment: @HansZ. I am not sure what you mean by that, the above function copies temp into b fine

Comment: sure, but you can use `b` only in the function `str_switch`; the code that called `str_switch` will have passed the initial value for `b` but it won't see the value that you copied in to it once `str_switch` returns; agree?

Comment: @HansZ. if you mean I cannot get the old value of b back, yes that is correct, but other than that, once I copy temp into b, b's value will have changed and will stay changed after the function.

Comment: eh, no, it is the opposite and that's what I worried about; see @Morpfh's answer

Comment: @HansZ. Ok why don't you try it. Declare a[] = "somestring"; b[]="anotherstring". Run my code and then print the value of b, I mean print the value b points to, it will be "somestring"

Comment: @HansZ. What you cannot change within the function is what variable b points to, you can however change the variable b points to through b, and that will stay changed

Comment: @HansZ. no I print it outside the function, I just tried it right now, that is the whole point of pointers, to change the value they point to within a function. the working code is the function above, you just need to declare a and b before the function, and then print b after the function

Comment: assuming you've allocated enough space for the string; problems arise when `strlen(a)` is greater than `strlen(b)`; try that... and as you indicated "the swapping should work irrespective of the sizes of b and a, and it is not known"

Comment: @Morpfh thanks yeah I know, your code is good if I want to change what the pointer is pointing to, through a higher class pointer, if i use it with char a[] it won't work because you cannot change what a points to if you declare it as char a[]